# How to show $\lim\frac{n^2+1}{n(n+1)}= 1$ by using the epsilon-delta definition.

Tags: limits

How to show $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^2+1}{n(n+1)}= 1$$ by using the epsilon-delta definition.

Step:

Fix $\varepsilon > 0$. There exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$, such that
$\left|\frac{n^2+1}{n(n+1)}-1 \right|< \varepsilon$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you start with $\frac{n^2+1}{n^2+n} = 1 - \frac{n -1 }{n^2+n}$. Now
$\left| \frac{n -1 }{n^2+n} \right| \le \left| \frac{n + 1 }{n^2+n} \right| = 1/n$ should finish it.